# Export MySQL table using php into excel. Problems with encoding

Tags: php, mysql, export-to-excel

I try to export one of MySQL table into excel file but polish letters aren't displaying correctly 
It is displayed:
Bre¶ć, Białoru¶
but should:
Brześć, Białoruś

How can I fix this code? It is really anoying that polish letters aren't displayed. Where could be a problem?

```
<?php

 $DB_Server = "localhost";      //your MySQL Server 
$DB_Username = "******";                 //your MySQL User Name 
$DB_Password = "*****";             //your MySQL Password 
$DB_DBName = "*******";             //your MySQL Database Name 
$DB_TBLName = "********";               //your MySQL Table Name  

 $filename = "excelfilename";         //File Name

 //create MySQL connection
 $sql = "Select * from $DB_TBLName";
 $Connect = @mysql_connect($DB_Server, $DB_Username, $DB_Password)
 or die("Couldn't connect to MySQL:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());
 //select database
 $Db = @mysql_select_db($DB_DBName, $Connect)
 or die("Couldn't select database:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());
 //execute query
 $result = @mysql_query($sql,$Connect)
 or die("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());
 $file_ending = "xls";

//header info for browser
 header("Content-Type: application/xls");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");
 header("Pragma: no-cache");
 header("Expires: 0");

/*******Start of Formatting for Excel*******/
 //define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
 $sep = "\t"; //tabbed character

//start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields
 for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++) {
 echo mysql_field_name($result,$i) . "\t";
 }
 print("\n");
 //end of printing column names

//start while loop to get data
 while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
 {
 $schema_insert = "";
 for($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)
 {
 if(!isset($row[$j]))
 $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
 elseif ($row[$j] != "")
 $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
 else
 $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
 }
 $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
 $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
 $schema_insert .= "\t";
 print(trim($schema_insert));
 print "\n";
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Writing to a csv file where you can't control the charset that Excel assumes when loading the file is never a good idea. Perhaps consider writing a UTF-8 BOM at the beginning of your file as a quick and dirty solution (assuming you're using UTF-8)

Comment: PS. Read about PHP's built-in [fputcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function to save youself a few lines of code

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: You could, alternatively use MySQL's built-in [SELECT INTO OUTFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html)

Comment: how to write UTF-8 BOM at the beginning?

Comment: In your case, as you're simply echoing: `echo chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF);`

Answer (score 0):

You have to write what is charset of you database. If it is UTF8 try to execute query "SET NAMES utf8" after connection is established ;

And be shure that encoding of you page is UTF8. You can check encoding in Notepad++ utility

Answer (score 0):

Problem is your output is in `ISO-8859-2` but excel expects `Windows-1250` which has few characters shuffled around for `Windows-1252` compatibility.

You can either convert your output to `Windows-1250`

```
echo mb_convert_encoding($str, 'Windows-1250', 'ISO-8859-2');
```

Or convert to utf8:

add utf8 BOM after headers and first thing as file content:

```
echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF";
```

and convert data to utf8

```
echo mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-2');
```

If you have older excel that does not support utf8 you are out of luck.

---

By default excel assumes windows default locale which is different for people from different locations i.e person in US will likely see your text as "Brze¶æ, Bia³oru¶" instead

Comment: `mb_convert_encoding($str, 'Windows-1250', 'ISO-8859-2');`